# Perl Web::Query Linebreak

Tags: perl

Is there a way to retrieve the text of a element fetched with Web::Query including the line breaks?

```
print wq('http://www.google.de')->find('p')->text;
```

any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `line breaks`? Tag `<br>` or `\n`? There is no such thing `\n` in html.

Comment: I mean the ```<br />``` tags, they are simply stripped out as any other tag. Can I keep them as ```\n``` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

use html() instead of text():

```
print wq('http://www.google.de')->find('p')->html;
```